# C++ Comparision operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What the difference between overloading operator< (as example) inside class or outside?

Why std map uses an outside implementation? But my comparison uses an inside one?

How can I know which implementation is needed to use?

Code bottom is code for test it that I used.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int val) : a(val) {}
    int getA() const { return a; }
    void setA(const int& val) { a = val; }

    inline bool operator<(const Foo& f)
    {
        cout<<"operator< inside\n";
        return a < f.getA();
    } 
    
private:
    int a = 1;
};

inline bool operator<(const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2)
{
    cout<<"operator< outside\n";
    return f1.getA() < f2.getA();
}

std::map<Foo, const char*> fMap = { {Foo(2), "Val 2"}, {Foo(3), "Val 3"} };

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    
    Foo f, f2;
    f.setA(3);
    f2.setA(7);
    
    cout << (f < f2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
operator< outside
operator< outside
Hello World
operator<
inside 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `std::map` the keys are `const`.  `Foo::operator<` is not const qualified, so you cannot call it on const objects.  That is the reason it is not used and your global operator is used instead.  To fix this, just change your `operator <` to

```
inline bool operator<(const Foo& f) const
{
    cout<<"operator< inside\n";
    return a < f.getA();
}
```